# Datastax Object Mapper: change table on the fly

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I have a need to change what table my mapping annoatation points to on  the fly.  Consider the below:

```
@Table(name="measurementtable_one", keyspace="mykeyspace")
public class Measurement {/*...*/}
```

I have multiple tables with the naming pattern 'measurementtable_*' whose names are not necessarily known at compile-time, and the one I need to work with is selected by the input to my program.  Since all of these tables are identical, I have no desire to create a new class for each table; and I have no desire to recompile my program for each input.

Is there a way to retain Object Mapping functionality without having to dictate my exact table name in the annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By conventional means, no.  Since annotations are effectively constants, you cannot change them by conventional means.  Since the Datastax object mapper does not expose any way to switch up tables for mapped object on the fly, darker arts must be employed: bytecode manipulation.

While one could have manipulated Measurement's annotation directly, I'm not a fan of changing what *should* be constant.  As a result, the `Measurement` class should lose its annotation and be made abstract:

```
public class Measurement { /*...*/ }
```

Then, once the real table name is known, one can use javassist to generate a subclass with the correct annotation:

```
String modelname = getNameFromExternalSource(); //Replace with real external source.
String modelcleanname = modeldir.getName().replaceAll("\\W", "");
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
String measurementclassname = "measurementtable_" + modelcleanname;
CtClass stagingmeasurementclass = pool.makeClass(measurementclassname);
stagingmeasurementclass.setSuperclass(pool.get(StagingMeasurementRecord.class.getName()));
stagingmeasurementclass.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
ClassFile stagingmeasurementclassfile = stagingmeasurementclass.getClassFile();
ConstPool constpool = stagingmeasurementclassfile.getConstPool();
AnnotationsAttribute attribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constpool,
        AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
Annotation tableannotation = new Annotation(constpool, pool.get(Table.class.getName()));
tableannotation.addMemberValue("name", new StringMemberValue(measurementclassname, constpool));
tableannotation.addMemberValue("keyspace", new StringMemberValue("mykeyspace", constpool));
attribute.addAnnotation(tableannotation);
stagingmeasurementclassfile.addAttribute(attribute);
stagingmeasurementclass.addConstructor(
        CtNewConstructor.make(new CtClass[0], new CtClass[0], stagingmeasurementclass));
Class<? super StagingMeasurementRecord> myoutputclass = stagingmeasurementclass.toClass();
LOGGER.info("Created custom measurementtable class with the name " + myoutputclass.getName());
```

You may then feed the `myoutputclass` instance to a `MappingManagerInstance.mapper(...)` call to produce an object mapper that points to your desired table.

It's not the prettiest solution out there, given that bytecode manipulation is necessary, but it does what it needs to do while avoiding recompiling for each input or making a million identical classes for your objects.